# find url of a specific wordpress page

Tags: php, wordpress

How do I find the the url of a WordPress page using the page name.

I have been trying to use get_page_link() however for that I need to find the page ID, is there a better way if all I have is the page name?
If not how do I get the page ID with the page name?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `get_page_by_title()`

```
<?php 
  $page = get_page_by_title( $page_title, $output, $post_type );
  $link = get_permalink($page->ID);
?>
```

From there you will be able to get page URL

Reference: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_by_title

Comment: When I use
<?php echo get_page_by_title("Home") ?>

I get the error

Catchable fatal error: Object of class WP_Post could not be converted to string in C:\wamp\www\learning\wp-content\themes\practice\page-home.php on line 25

Comment: Result of `get_page_by_title()` is not a string. It's a WP_Post object. In order to get page URL, you need to call `get_permalink($post->ID)`. I updated my answer

Comment: If this work for you, consider marking my answer as approved.

Comment: How do I approve the answer?

Answer (score 0):

`get_page_by_title` linked in the accepted answer is deprecated. You can use `get_page_by_path` assuming you know the path which is similar (if not the same) to the title.

Below code will output the link to the page.

```
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink(get_page_by_path('path')->ID )); ?>">
    <?php _e( get_page_by_path('path')->post_title) ?> 
</a>
```